# Find $\iint \limits_{S} \vec{F}\cdot \vec{N} dA$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

I have to find $$\iint \limits_{S} \vec{F}\cdot \vec{N} dA$$ where $$\vec{F} = (2x^2,\frac{y^2}{2},-cos\pi z)$$ and S is the surface of tetrahedron of vertices
$$(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$$

we know that from Gauss Divergence theorem that,

$$\iint\limits_{S} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{N} dA = \iiint\limits_{V} div \vec{F} dV$$

The divergence of the given Function is,

$$div \vec{F} = 4x + y + \pi sin \pi z$$

so $$\iint\limits_{S} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{N} dA = \iiint\limits_{V} 4x + y + \pi sin \pi z dV$$

But I am stuck finding the limit of integration.How to find the limits? What procedure should I follow.

I am really struggling to find the limit of integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the surface integral using divergence theorem is

$ \displaystyle \iiint_{E} (4x + y + \pi \sin \pi z) ~dV$

where region $E$ is interior of the tetrahedron. The tetrahedron is bound by x, y and z coordinate planes, and the plane $x + y +z = 1$

The projection of the region in xy-plane is  $~x + y \leq 1, x, y \ge 0$.

So the integral will be,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} \int_0^{1- x - y} (4x + y + \pi \sin \pi z) ~ dz ~ dy ~ dx$

You can write the integral in any order but for $ \sin \pi z$ component, integrating wrt $~dz$ first may be a bit easier to evaluate .

Comment: how did you find the range, does not all x,y,z range from 0 to 1?

Comment: Use coordinates of four vertices. You pick any of the three vertices out of four and that gives you one of the faces of the tetrahedron. For example $(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)$ all have $x = 0$ and that is one of the faces. Similarly others give you planes $y = 0, z = 0$. The last one is the face having vertices $(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)$ and that is $x + y + z = 1$.

Comment: So for any given $x$ and $y$, a vertical strip along $z$ goes from plane $z = 0$ to $x + y + z = 1 \implies z = 1 - x - y$

Comment: If you let $x, y, z$ range freely between $(0, 1)$, you are talking about a cube and not a tetrahedron which has one of the surfaces as $x + y + z = 1$. Here, $x + y + z$ cannot be greater than $1$ but if they all range in $(0, 1)$, you have $~0 \leq x + y + z \leq 3$, which is wrong.